# Convert DataTable to Linq

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, linq-to-sql, .net-3.5

I'm trying to convert DataTable to Linq
using

```
DIm result = From r in dt.AsEnumerable()
             Select new ( col1 = r.Field<integer>("id"), col2 = r.Field<string>("desc"))
```

But i get error near 'new (' saying type expected.

What is wrong with this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531249.aspx says to use the syntax

```
New With { ... }
```

Comment: it worked but when i try to use result to do another linq query on it says result not declared

Answer (score 0):

I thought it was New { ... }

**Edit:**  it is `New With` in VB.  Confusing my C# and VB again.  I can't see why (as the comment to the accepted answer says), "result" wouldn't be declared.  Without a code sample, it's hard to tell.

Comment: your answer appeared on the review tool. As it appears there it looks more like a comment or a suggestion, not a real answer. Also we can't see the other answers, just that one that is flagged by the community or automatic selected by the system.

Comment: I see.  That is a little silly of then tool then; I would think the context would be needed.  Anyway, reading the original question closely makes it clear he was trying to fix the query, though the language above the code sample also confused *me* when I came back to look at it!  Glad somebody is going back through these (somehow) and fixing them this way.  Thanks for your work.

Comment: Thanks. I can't remove my vote (is one way only), but since you edited your question, other peers will see it and flag as useful ;)

Comment: No problem.  I'm not in this for rep, don't have the time to prowl /new :)